# ILMerge error: SQLite.Interop.dll [Could not load assembly from the location]

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, dll

The problem is when I want to merge my .exe with those DLLs.

When I try to merge them, there appears an error: An exception occurred during merging:

ILMerge.Merge: Could not load assembly from the location 'D:\MyProject\bin\Release\SQLite.Interop.dll'. Skipping and processing rest of arguments.
1>     at ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
1>     at ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)

Answer (score 3):

SQLite.Interop.dll is the [native interop asembly](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) and is **NOT** a managed assembly. (You can verify that by trying to open SQLite.interop.dll  with [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) or [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

ILMerge is only capable of 'merging' managed assemblies into one executable. So basically what you are trying is not possible.

You either have to create an installer (MSI) or create an bootstrapper executable that holds all required files a resources and extract those to a tempfolder after which the extracted exe file is executed.